# Display the number of additions and deletions per commit for a file

Tags: git

Is there a way [to do the following](https://gist.github.com/AJamesPhillips/0ccd99c1d1841a8a66db4b4647a30512) but only by using git commands:

```
$ ./git_helper.py index.d.ts
commit  added deleted            commit message
bd1de57 4     4       index.d.ts Error object fix
c3a54db 25    120     index.d.ts Merge branch 'master' into types-2.0
e9a0e98 58    10      index.d.ts Merge commit 'upstream/master~300' into merge_7_25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the files with --stat

```
git log --stat --decorate --graph --oneline
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
gitk your_commit_here
```

Comment: `git log --stat --oneline` is pretty close to what that whole script does.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually I always use "git log --stat --oneline --graph --all" to see all branches. Also gitk command by itself shows you the files too.